# JQuery .val() returning html (not the value of the input field)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given the html:

```
<div id="rearGearInputContainer">
    <input id="rear1"></input>
    <input id="rear2"></input>
    <input id="rear3"></input>
    <input id="rear4"></input>
</div>
```

In the Chrome console I type:

```
$('#rearGearInputContainer').find("input").each(function () {return $(this).val();})
```

And the result is an array of html:

```
[<input id=​"rear1">​, <input id=​"rear2">​, <input id=​"rear3">​, <input id=​"rear4">​]
```

...not an array of the input field values as I'd expect. Can anyone explain why? Thanks.

Comment: put in jsfiddle & share the link plz.

Comment: none of your input fields have values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to return in an each method, which I don't think you want. I think you mean to use the `map()` method:

```
var vals = $('#rearGearInputContainer').find("input").map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
}).get()
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/ZDV5C/)

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the delay - notifications from StackOverflow not set up correctly so I assumed nobody had answered. This solves my problem, but I still can't understand why .each() didn't do what I wanted. JQuery docs:  _".each(): Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element."_  Any ideas?

Comment: `.each()` won't return an array, it returns the jQuery object. You could use `.each()` here but would need to push to an existing array within the loop. http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/ZDV5C/2/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/375N3/

```
$('#rearGearInputContainer input').each(function () {
   alert($(this).val());
})
```